# Import a new file type in R

Tags: r, file, file-conversion

I would like to create a function that imports this syntax-type files to R. The format of those files looks like:

```
!!!
!!!
!!!
!!!
!!!
!!!
!!!
!!!
**kern  **dynam **kern  **dynam  <--------Here is determined the number of columns (4)
*staff2 *   *staff1 *staff1/2
*>[A,A,B,B] *   *>[A,A,B,B] *>[A,A,B,B]
*>norep[A,B]    *   *>norep[A,B]    *>norep[A,B]
*>A *   *>A *>A
*clefF4 *   *clefG2 *clefG2
*k[b-]  *   *k[b-]  *k[b-]
*F: *   *F: *F:
*M3/4   *   *M3/4   *M3/4
*MM108  *   *MM108  *MM108
16r .   16f f
=1  =1  =1  =1
!LO:TX:b:i:t=legato !   !   !
12FL    .   4cc .
12A .   .   .
12cJ    .   .   .
.   .   (32bnqq/    .
12GL    .   4cc)    .
12B-    .   .   .
12cJ    .   .   .
.   .   (32bqLLL>   .
.   .   32ccq   .
.   .   32ddqJJJ    .
12FL    .   4cc)    .
12A .   .   .
12cJ    .   .   .
=2  =2  =2  =2
*Xtuplet    *   *Xtuplet    *
```

Therefore, somehow the file could be converted to csv to be imported in R. The number of columns could vary in each file (normally 1 to 50).

I tried *`data_imported<-import("sonata.krn", format = "csv")`* but I got the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In fread(dec = ".", input = "son.krn", sep = "auto", header = "auto",  :
  Detected 1 column names but the data has 4 columns (i.e. invalid file). Added 3 extra default column names at the end.
2: In fread(dec = ".", input = "son.krn", sep = "auto", header = "auto",  :
  Stopped early on line 101. Expected 4 fields but found 5. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<4FF 4F      .       (<12g 12b-L     2ryy    f>>
```

However, the first part of the file is shown in the console. The thing is that I want to automatize the task, so the header should be removed by using a function in R...but if I cannot import this file, that's not possible.

Thank you in advance, any ideas will be rewarded!

Comment: If you don't need the info in the header (and the same # of header lines appears in each Humdrum file), consider using the `skip` arg of `read.table` to skip past the !!! lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below imports the header as a named character vector and the data as a data frame.

```
fn <- "sonata.krn"

# Read all the lines
lines <- readLines(con = fn)

# Get the header and the data
start <- 1
while (grepl("^!!!", lines[start])) {
  start <- start + 1
}

header <- lines[1:(start - 1)]
# Convert the header into a named vector
names(header) <- gsub("^!!!([[:alpha:][:digit:]]+):.*", "\\1", header)
header <- gsub("^!!![[:alpha:][:digit:]]+: ", "", header)

# Lines containing the data
lines <- lines[-(1:(start - 1))]

# Substitute TABs for column delimiters
lines <- gsub(" +", "\t", lines)

# Import the data
d <- read.delim(textConnection(lines), sep = "\t",
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Some additional data cleaning is probably necessary but that should be pretty straightforward.